# SonarQube 5.1 execution error using Bamboo

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe running on my own computer and everything is working fine. I am now trying to automate this job and give it to Bamboo. I am using the same SonarQube configuration (but not the same environment as it is a Windows 2008 R2 Server versus Windows 7). I am using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe with the simplest configuration file (only the MySQL server).

My error indicates a path to Dinesh's desktop (if I'm not mistaking, he's a Sonar Qube developer)

This error happens after running  **MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end**. Any idea ?

```
18:00:06  Writing processing summary to E:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SON-SVACN0-TEST\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log
18:00:06  Creating directory: E:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SON-SVACN0-TEST\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner
18:00:06  The SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable is not required and will be ignored.
18:00:06  Calling the sonar-runner...
18:00:06  SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_Runner'  Key being added: 'bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_runner'
  at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
  at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
  at System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionaryWithComparer.Add(String key, String value)
  at System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.get_EnvironmentVariables()
  at SonarQube.Common.ProcessRunner.SetEnvironmentVariables(ProcessStartInfo psi, IDictionary`2 envVariables, ILogger logger) in c:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\sonarsource\sonar-msbuild-runner\SonarQube.Common\ProcessRunner.cs:line 151
  at SonarQube.Common.ProcessRunner.Execute(String exeName, String args, String workingDirectory, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, IDictionary`2 envVariables, ILogger logger) in c:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\sonarsource\sonar-msbuild-runner\SonarQube.Common\ProcessRunner.cs:line 87
  at SonarRunner.Shim.SonarRunnerWrapper.ExecuteJavaRunner(ILogger logger, String exeFileName, String propertiesFileName) in c:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\sonarsource\sonar-msbuild-runner\SonarRunner.Shim\SonarRunner.Wrapper.cs:line 114
  at SonarRunner.Shim.SonarRunnerWrapper.Execute(AnalysisConfig config, ILogger logger) in c:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\sonarsource\sonar-msbuild-runner\SonarRunner.Shim\SonarRunner.Wrapper.cs:line 68
  at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.Program.Main() in c:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\sonarsource\sonar-msbuild-runner\SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor\Program.cs:line 51
```

Comment: FYI you're seeing paths on my local machine because I have performed the release, which includes *.pdb files. The files contain absolute paths to the source files on the machine using to build the assemblies. With them, stack traces are augmented with source information. The actual root cause of the failure you are getting is unrelated.

Comment: All right, thank you for your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, environment variables are case-insensitive.
For some reason, you are trying to define both:

1. bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_**R**unner
2. bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_**r**unner

This is not well supported by the .NET framework, see:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/ProcessStartInfo.cs#L97

Any call to `ProcessStartInfo.Environment` when the same environment variable exists with multiple casing will result in the failure you see.

So - perhaps this is something to be fixed in CoreFX (the .NET Framework) - but I do not think a change in the MSBuild SonarQube Runner itself is required.

Another fix is to have Bamboo not to define the same environment variable multiple times. For example, the Windows User Interface to set environment variables overwrites the value if you attempt to define `FOO` when `foo` is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo is creating many environment variables. The problem is that it creates two times the same variable (**R**unner vs **r**unner).

```
bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_Runner=E:\sonar-runner-2.3
bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_runner=E:\sonar-runner-2.3
bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_runners=E:\sonar-runner-2.3
```

I think there is a bug in MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner as it should check that the key is already contained in this function

```
  at SonarQube.Common.ProcessRunner.SetEnvironmentVariables(ProcessStartInfo psi, IDictionary`2 envVariables, ILogger logger) in c:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\sonarsource\sonar-msbuild-runner\SonarQube.Common\ProcessRunner.cs:line 151
```

As a quick workaround I decided to set one of the two variables to null in my bamboo script:

```
set bamboo_capability_system_builder_snr_Sonar_runner=
```